# Assigning a single value to all cells within a specified time period, matrix format

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have the following example dataset which consists of the # of fish caught per check of a net.  The nets are not checked at uniform intervals.  The day of the check is denoted in julian days as well as the number of days the net had been fishing since last checked (or since it's deployment in the case of the first check)

http://textuploader.com/9ybp

```
Site_Number Check_Day_Julian    Set_Duration_Days   Fish_Caught
2   5   3   100
2   10  5   70
2   12  2   65
2   15  3   22
100 4   3   45
100 10  6   20
100 18  8   8
450 10  10  10
450 14  4   4
```

In any case, I would like to turn the raw data above into the following format:

http://textuploader.com/9y3t

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
2   0   0   100 100 100 70  70  70  70  70  65  65  22  22  22  0   0   0
100 0   45  45  45  20  20  20  20  20  20  8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
450 10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  4   4   4   4   0   0   0   0
```

This is a matrix which assigns the # of fish caught during the period to EACH of the days that were within that period.  The columns of the matrix are Julian days, the rows are site numbers.

I have tried to do this with some matrix functions but I have had much difficulty trying to populate all the fields that are within the time period, but I do not necessarily have a row of data for?

I had posted my small bit of code here, but upon reflection, my approach is quite archaic and a bit off point.  Can anyone suggest a method to convert the data into the matrix provided?  I've been scratching my head and googling all day but now I am stumped.

Cheers,
C

Comment: Please include example data in the question itself.

Comment: If I paste it in text it gets quite jumbled.  Do I add it in as code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two answers, the second one is faster but a bit low level.

Solution #1:

```
library(IRanges)
with(d, {
  ir <- IRanges(end=Check_Day_Julian, width=Set_Duration_Days)
  cov <- coverage(split(ir, Site_Number),
                  weight=split(Fish_Caught, Site_Number),
                  width=max(end(ir)))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(cov, as.vector))
})
```

Solution #2:

```
with(d, {
  ir <- IRanges(end=Check_Day_Julian, width=Set_Duration_Days)
  site <- factor(Site_Number, unique(Site_Number))
  m <- matrix(0, length(levels(site)), max(end(ir)))
  ind <- cbind(rep(site, width(ir)), as.integer(ir))
  m[ind] <- rep(Fish_Caught, width(ir))
  m              
})
```

Comment: I used the second option with great success, thanks!!  Is there any way for me to get the site number as a row label so I can double check my data??  I've been playing around with this but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a super obvious matrix transformation here. This is all i've got assuming the raw data is in a data.frame called `dd`

```
dd$Site_Number<-factor(dd$Site_Number)

mm<-matrix(0, nrow=nlevels(dd$Site_Number), ncol=18)
for(i in 1:nrow(dd)) {
    mm[as.numeric(dd[i,1]), (dd[i,2]-dd[i,3]):dd[i,2] ] <- dd[i,4]
}
mm
```